# Preserve this and preserve jQuery context

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am using `bind()` to preserve `this` (which is an instance of my class) inside my jQuery functions:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { 
    Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        object = args.shift(); 
    return function(){ 
        return fn.apply(object, 
             args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
        }; 
    };
}
```

The problem is if I have a click event for example and I can no longer access the element using `$(this)` and no should I be able to.

e.g:

```
View.prototype.sayHelloBind = function(){
    this.$el.find('#bind').on('click', (function(){

        // This no longer works
        $(this).css('color', 'red');

        alert(this.message);
    }).bind(this));
}
```

As you will see in the JSFiddle I am aware of using `e.data`, that is, in fact, the reason I want to use `bind()` so I can get away from that syntax.

My question is, is there a way to use `bind()` to preserve `this` as well as have access to a the current jQuery object?

[Relevant JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfBgm/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Using (your) original `bind()`

```
View.prototype.sayHelloBind = function(){
    var el = this.$el.find('#bind');
    el.on('click', (function(elem){
        $(elem).css('border', '1px solid red')
        alert(this.message);
    }).bind(this, el));
}
```

Downside: no `event` in context.

---

### 2) You could create your own variation of `bind()`:

```
//if (!Function.prototype.bind_elem) {
  Function.prototype.bind_elem = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var that = args.shift(); // view
    var obj = args.shift(); // DOM object
    return function(event){ 
        var argggs = [event, obj].concat(args);
        return fn.apply(that, argggs); 
    }; 
  };
//}


var View = function(element, msg){
    this.$el = $(element);    
    this.message = msg;
}

View.prototype.sayHelloBind = function(){
    var el = this.$el.find('#bind');
    el.on('click', (function(event, elem){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(elem).css('border', '1px solid red')
        alert(this.message);
    }).bind_elem(this, el));
}

$(function(){
    var view = new View('#test', 'Hello World!');
    view.sayHelloBind();
});
```

A complete JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cek125i/24AmT/

I have added `event` in the context, because it is often useful.

A downside is that we have to refer to `el` twice:

```
el.on('click', (func...).bind_elem(this, el));
```

I don't see a way around that...

---

### 3) The KISS principle?

If the use case is not particularly complex, maybe use something a lot more simple:

```
View.prototype.sayHelloBind = function(){
    var el = this.$el.find('#bind');
    var that = this;
    el.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red')
        alert(that.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) in this case to refer the current element

```
View.prototype.sayHelloBind = function(){
    this.$el.find('#bind').on('click', (function(event){

        // This no longer works
        $(event.currentTarget).css('color', 'red');

        alert(this.message);
    }).bind(this));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JXg7U/)

Instead of using [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), jQuery provides a cross platform implementation called [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

```
View.prototype.sayHelloBind = function(){
    this.$el.find('#bind').on('click', $.proxy(function(event){

        // This no longer works
        $(event.currentTarget).css('color', 'red');

        alert(this.message);
    }, this));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YfmG5/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` within the event handler must either be the default (i.e. the clicked element) or it may be your container object, it cannot be both.

Since the default semantics are the ones that people are most used to, why not:

```
View.prototype.sayHelloBind = function() {
    var self = this;          // copy of "this" to use inside the closure
    this.$el.find('#bind').on('click', function() {

        $(this).css('color', 'red');

        alert(self.message);  // use the closed variable
    });
}
```

This is actually more efficient than using `.bind` and also avoids the shim.  `.bind` has to create and return an entire new function that closes over `this` and its arguments, so why not just use the language's own features and close over `this` yourself?